# Java Binary Tree insert method not working

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am making a recursive insert method for a binary tree. This method is not able to add nodes to the tree. i cant seem to find whats wrong with this method. the constructor takes a string label for the child and a parent node.

```
 public void insert(String aLabel) {

    //if compare is positive add to right else add to left
    //basis case:
    BSTreeNode aNode = new BSTreeNode(aLabel,null);
    if (aNode.parent == null) {
        aNode.parent = this;
    }
    inserts(this,aNode);
}
private void inserts(BSTreeNode aParent, BSTreeNode aNode){
    //initially the root node is the parent however a proper parent is found thorough recursion
    //left recursion:
    if(aParent.getLabel().compareTo(aNode.getLabel()) <= 0) {
        if (this.childrenLeft == null) {
            this.childrenLeft = aNode;
            aNode.parent = this;
            return;
        } else {
            childrenLeft.inserts(childrenLeft, aNode);
        }
    }
    //right recursion
    else {
        if (this.childrenRight==null) {
            this.childrenRight = aNode;
            return;
        }
        else{
            childrenRight.inserts(childrenRight,aNode);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: whats the problem ? Is it just not generating proper BST or you getting any exception ? Your condition of first if clause seems wrong. Just check. You have checked if parent is lesser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer refers to the original version of the question.

When you call `inserts(this.childrenLeft, aNode);` you are still at the same node; i.e. `this` still refers to the old parent.

Instead you should do something like:

```
childrenLeft.insert(childrenLeft, aNode);
```

In fact, the first parameter of `insert` is redundant, you should refactor to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need something like this.

The code is commented so you understand what is going on...

```
// insert method takes The Node as a param and a value to store in BT
public void insert(Node node, int value) {

//Check that the value param is less than the Node (root) value,
// If so insert the data to the left of the root node. Else insert        
// the right node as it is a larger number than root
if (value < node.value) {
  if (node.left != null) {
    insert(node.left, value);
  } else {
    System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of "
        + node.value);
    node.left = new Node(value);
  }
} else if (value > node.value) {
  if (node.right != null) {
    insert(node.right, value);
  } else {
    System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of "
        + node.value);
    node.right = new Node(value);
  }
 }
}
```